# Regex whitespace, brackets, and parens

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a string in the following form:

```
require([ "foo/bar", "foo2/bar2" ])
```

Whitespace should be ignored entirely. I am using the following regex with little success:

```
require\\(\s*\\[[.\s]*\\]\\)
```

Any suggestions? I know that regex attempt is horrible...

**EDIT:** I am using Python!

Comment: What is your programming language anyway?

Comment: @inhan You may assume the common subset is available.

Comment: @JanDvorak the question is relevant to the escape sequence, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java or PHP with double-quoted strings or somethig similar, you need to double escape the `\s` as well. If not, then you need to remove all double backslashes instead (and make them single backslashes). Also note, that `[.\s]` matches only periods and whitespace (`.` loses its wildcard meaning within character classes). If you really want to match **anything** use `[\s\S]` instead.

Assuming double escaping is required in the language you use:

```
require\\(\\s*\\[[\\S\\s]*\\]\\)
```

Note that this will cause problems if this occurs multiple times in the same string. Then you would get a match from the first `require([` to the last `])`. To avoid this, disallow `]` within the repetition. However, be aware that this in turn can cause problems if your strings within `require` may contain `]` themselves:

```
require\\(\\s*\\[[^]]*\\]\\)
```

Comment: Could not have asked for a better answer. Thanks so much. If I knew you in person I'd buy you a beer.

Comment: @user1738992 since you are using Python you could also use a raw string instead and escape everything with only a single backslash.